# Acceder a la información de un archivo Json en C++

Tags: c++, json

tengo el siguiente archivos en formato Json:

```
{
    "songs":[
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "My Way",
            "artist": "Calvin Harris",
            "minutes": 3,
            "seconds": 39,
        },
        {
            "id": 201,
            "name": "Don’t be shy",
            "artist": "Don’t be shy",
            "minutes": 2,
            "seconds": 20,
        },
        {
            "id": 234,
            "name": "Hey Brother",
            "artist": "Avicii",
            "minutes": 4,
            "seconds": 15,
        },
        {
            "id": 54,
            "name": "Ojitos Lindos",
            "artist": "J Balvin, Willy William",
            "minutes": 4,
            "seconds": 18,
        },
        {
            "id": 06,
            "name": "Mi gente",
            "artist": "J Balvin, Willy William",
            "minutes": 3,
            "seconds": 5,
        },
    ]
}
```

Mi pregunta es que tengo que ordenar cada canción por el número de su "id", el algoritmo de ordenamiento ya lo tengo hecho, entonces quería saber como poder acceder a la información del archivo para obtener la "id" de cada canción y así poder ordenarlas,, y si de poder hacerlo, al momento de mostrarlas ya ordenadas se pudiese imprimir también la información de cada canción según su id.

Comment: Podrías usar una librería para facilitar el trabajo. Por ejemplo esta: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Answer (score 1):

Según [esta documentación](https://xtokio.github.io/blog/2017/c-con-json/), podrías acceder a los datos de tus JSON de esta forma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream ifs("canciones.json"); // ruta de mi archivo json
    Json::Reader reader; // leemos el json
    Json::Value obj; // referenciamos a "obj" como un valor.
    reader.parse(ifs, obj); // parseamos al json con sus objetos
    const Json::Value& objeto = obj["songs"]; // ingresamos a los objetos que contiene "songs"
    for (int i = 0; i < objeto.size(); i++){ // recorremos a los objetos
        cout << "\n id: " << objeto[i]["id"].asInt(); // ingresamos a los id
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```